# Probability question: How many ways can you rank the 1st place and 2nd place people?

Tags: probability

"There are 5 people in a race: A, B, C, D and E. If the first place and second place positions are selected randomly, what is the probability that A would be first place and B would be second place?" I understand that there are 120 ways that the heat could be ranked, but I'm not really sure where to go from there, so I would love some help! Thanks

Comment: The problem only concerns first and second place, so you only need to consider the ranking of the top two people.

Comment: Observe that there is only one way for $A$ to finish first and $B$ to finish second.  If you use $5!$ as your denominator, you have to multiply the number of ways $A$ can finish first and $B$ finish second by the number of ways $C$, $D$, and $E$ can fill the remaining places.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. There are 120 ways to complete the rankings in any order. Now how many of these ways have A in first place and B in second? Tip: Fix A in 1st place, B in 2nd and try to compute how many ways the other 3 players can rank.

Then to work out the probability, it would be $$\Bbb P(\text{A is 1st, B is 2nd})=\frac{\text{# of ways A is 1st, B is 2nd}}{\text{# of all possible combinations}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways in which A finishes 1st and B finishes 2nd is = 1*1*3!

3! is the number of ways of arranging C, D and E at 3rd,4th and 5th position.A and B can be placed at 1st and 2nd places in 1 ways only.
The total number of possible combination = 5!

Probaility=(1*1*3!)/5!
          =1/20

Comment: Did you mean the total number of possible permutations?